# jquery url query parameters

Tags: jquery, html, url, query-string

```
window.open(str);
```

This returns `/FindJobs.aspx?k=keyword&l=location` in the url bar.

```
window.location.href = str;
```

This returns `/FindJobs.aspx` in the url bar.

Both are working off of the same script and same values.

The only way window.loaction.href shows the parameters is when I use firebug to step through the script.

I need the parameters to show up when using both window.open and window.location.href

Please help,
g5

For what its worth all scripts are loaded in correct order and are added at the bottom of my pages just before . The team I'm working with requires we do it this way.

```
<div class="span5">
  <input type="text" id="Keyword" name="keyword" placeholder="Keyword..." class="span12 inFieldLabel">
</div>
<div class="span4">
  <input type="text" id="Location" name="location" placeholder="Location..." class="span12 inFieldLabel">
 </div>

<div class="row-fluid">
 <a id="searchJobs_Button" href="/FindJobs" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Find Job »</a>
</div>  

$("#searchJobs_Button").click(function () {
    var str = "/FindJobs.aspx" +
    "?k=" + encodeURIComponent($("#Keyword").val()) +
    "&l=" + encodeURIComponent($("#Location").val());
    alert(str);
    window.location.href = str;
    window.open(str);
});
```

Comment: This works fine for me. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mqj4X/

Comment: By the way, you can also assemble a complete URI and use [`.encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FencodeURI) on all of it at once. -- http://jsfiddle.net/Mqj4X/1/